# How to change textfield font size programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button that creates a text field, I also have a button to change the text field's font. I created 3 button with different titles: `17,20,36`. I want the functions of that button to change the font size of the text field, how can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to simply change your textfield's font size , and not change it's font style at the same time , code below may be work : `

```
UITextField *yourTextField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
CGFloat yourSelectedFontSize = 14.0 ;
UIFont *yourNewSameStyleFont = [yourTextField.font fontWithSize:yourSelectedFontSize];
yourTextField.font = yourNewSameStyleFont ;
```

One thing you have to note is that : when you change your textfield's font size , you should always pay attention to your textfield view's height , keep your textfiled's height taller than your font height !

You can have a try !

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4** is this:

```
yourTextField.font =  UIFont.init(name: (Montserrat.bold.rawValue), size: 18.0)
```

Instead Monserrat use your font

Comment: Rewrite the style and change font size

Comment: yourTextField.font =  UIFont.init(name: (Montserrat.bold.rawValue), size: 15.0)

Comment: will this work??  presenter.mtf.font?.withSize(CGFloat(n))

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3** Version of accepted answer:

```
let yourTextField = UITextField()
let customFont:UIFont = UIFont.init(name: (textField.font?.fontName)!, size: 14.0)!
font = customFont
yourTextField.font = customFont
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it.

but you have to change the textField's frame also(to show the full(height) text)

```
[tFild_1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17]];
```

instead of "Helvetica Neue" use your font name.

thanx,

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NSAttributedString` to add properties to `TextField`

```
let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: /* TODO: fill in appropriate UIColor */,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: /* TODO: fill in appropriate UIColor */,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 40)!,
        NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth:  /* TODO: fill in appropriate Float */
    ]

yourTextField.defaultTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4:

```
textField1.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 22)
```